# What is meant by "Fired Callback"

Tags: javascript

I want to know how a directory in a node js file and files in that directory can read.On googling I got  following code

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir( process.argv[2], function (err, files) { 
if (!err) 
console.log(files);
else
throw err; 
});
console.log("Fired callback.");
```

Now I want to know what is meant by Fired Callback??????????????????
and process.argv[2]
In some places there is process.cwd() 
what does it means.
So that I can implement code according to my need ...

Answer (score 1):

"Fired callback." means that a callback function was called.  It's usually the kind of thing you see/use *within a callback* during debugging etc, to track down execution paths -- particularly in non-linear code --  and verify that the code is following the path it should.

In your case, though, unless that code is in a callback function of its own, the statement is incorrect.  Since `fs.readdir` is asynchronous, and the callback doesn't set any kind of flag etc, the code after `fs.readdir(...)` can't legitimately know the callback ran.

Comment: @Amadan: In this case, more than likely.  But in some cases, it's possible to know a task is already complete, in which case the callback might run immediately.  It's bad design to care either way, though; async only works decently when you don't assume *when* stuff will happen.

Comment: Good point, haven't considered possible optimisation. Apologies.